# Check and set the visibility of table rows

Tags: javascript, row, visible

I have a table with a few rows, in which each row becomes visible if the field in the row above it is not blank. I have written a working script, but I am new to Javascript and feel like it is too involved. In other words, is there a better, more concise solution to this problem? I would need to perform the same solution in several locations, so a better solution would be very welcome.

```
<script language="javascript">
   function MyTableRow(){
    //Row 1
 if(document.getElementById("DQ23I1010").value=="") 
  {
    //alert("test");
    document.getElementById("myRow1").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow1").style.display='block';   
}

 //Row 2
if(document.getElementById("DQ24I1011").value=="") 
  {
    document.getElementById("myRow2").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow2").style.display='block';   
}
//Row 3
if(document.getElementById("DQ25I1012").value=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("myRow3").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow3").style.display='block';   
}
//Row 4
if(document.getElementById("DQ26I1013").value=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("myRow4").style.display='none';
 }
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow4").style.display='block';   
}
//Row 5
   if(document.getElementById("DQ27I1014").value=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("myRow5").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow5").style.display='block';   
}
//Row 6
if(document.getElementById("DQ28I1015").value=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("myRow6").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow6").style.display='block';   
}
//Row 7
if(document.getElementById("DQ29I1016").value=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("myRow7").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow7").style.display='block';   
}
 //Row 8
 if(document.getElementById("DQ30I1017").value=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("myRow8").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow8").style.display='block';   
}
  //Row 9
if(document.getElementById("DQ31I1018").value=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("myRow9").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow9").style.display='block';   
}
 //Row 10
 if(document.getElementById("DQ32I1019").value=="") 
{
    document.getElementById("myRow10").style.display='none';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("myRow10").style.display='block';   
}
} 

</script>
```

Comment: are you trying to do this with only pure js?

Comment: you can start by making a function to get elements `function elm(id){return document.getElementById(id)}`

Comment: @jk1844—Do not set table rows to "block", their default *display* value is [table-row](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html). Toggle between "none" and "" (empty string) so the element will adopt it's default or whatever has been set otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can easily be shortened...

```
function MyTableRow() {
   for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       var row = document.getElementById("myRow" + i);
       if (document.getElementById("DQ" + (22 + i) + "I10" + (i + 9)).value == "")
           row.style.display = 'none';
       else
           row.style.display = '';  
   }
}
```

There's probably an even better solution that this, but we'd need more information.

Comment: +1 I favor jqueryless answers over jquery ones, specially when someone is new to JS. (I think jquery do more harm than help when one doesn't know the basics of JS)

Comment: Do not set table rows to "block", their default *display* value is [table-row](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html). Toggle between "none" and "" (empty string) so the element will adopt it's default or whatever has been set otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can help you do something like that, set your row class to class="row"

```
<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then you code looks something like this:

```
var showRow = true;
$(".row").each(function(index){
    if (!showRow) {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    }
    if ($this.find(".dataItem").val() == "") {
        showRow = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i am totally new to this... is there a example you could kindly do for me in jsfiddle.net. much appriciated

Comment: This isn't equivalent to the code in the question. And I don't see that OP is using jQuery.